# How to instantiate a class using info from a properties file?

Tags: java

I have a project with sorting algorithms, I need to use a properties file to set the algorithm that I will use, my properties file looks like this:

```
sorter=metodosOrdenamiento.QuickSorterImpl
```

where "metodosOrdenamiento" is the package and "QuickSorterImpl" is my class.
I'm trying this:

```
public static Sorter getInstance() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        Class<?> myClass = null;
        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream("java_3/MiFactory.properties"));
            myClass = Class.forName(properties.get("sorter").toString());

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No se pudo obtener la clase");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert myClass != null;
        return (Sorter)myClass.newInstance();
    }
```

But it produces a "ClassNotFoundException", Which is the correct way to instantiate the class from the properties file?

Comment: First, determine which part is broken. Does `myClass = Class.forName("metodosOrdenamiento.QuickSorterImpl");` work? If so, then your `properties` aren't loading correctly (which is my guess).

Comment: There are two possible issues here: A) your classpath setup is wrong B) the class name you are using is wrong. So: look at the stack trace. It tells you the exact name of the class to load. If the name is valid: then your class path is wrong. If the name is not valid, then fix that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't set your classpath correctly - as per @Elliott Frisch comment, and you are using deprecated API `Class.newInstance()`. Use `Class.getConstructor().newInstance()` IF there is a no-args constructor.

It is much easier to debug if you test both the constructor and classpath by hardwiring the class:

```
public static Sorter getInstance() throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Class<?> myClass = metodosOrdenamiento.QuickSorterImpl.class;
    assert myClass != null;
    return (Sorter)myClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

If that works, switch to load the classname from properties file:

```
private static Properties getProperties() {
    String name = "java_3/MiFactory.properties";
    try(var in = new FileInputStream(name))
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);
        return properties;
    } catch (IOException io)  {
        throw new UncheckedIOException("Could not find: "+name,io);
    }
}
public static Sorter getInstance() throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(getProperties().getProperty("sorter"));
    assert myClass != null;
    return (Sorter)myClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Note that the usage of `assert` requires the `-ea` flag to be set at application start else it will be ignored by the JVM

Answer (score -2):

You  can try to use following code

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath));
```

Comment: Your answer tells readers how to correctly read a properties file from the classpath. How does that answer a question that asks about loading classes dynamically?

Comment: Your answer assumes that Daniel is having problems loading the properties file, when we actually don't know yet for sure. Maybe the class he wants to load is not yet on the classpath, as shipped with a different JAR that is not added to the CP on application start and not loaded afterwards via a custom classloader, or the fully-qualified class name is not correct either. Maybe his properties file is also not directly on the classpath but in a dedicated configuration location like `/etc` on *nix environments or the like